# MongoDB collection index size using new array field takes more size than expected

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

MongoDB collection index size using new array field takes more size than expected.

This is a multikey index with an array field as the preceding index column in a collection which  already has millions of documents.

index = flavors.id_1_status_1_createdDate_1

```
db.icecream.createIndex(
    { "flavors.id": 1, "status": 1, "createdDate": 1 },
    {
        background: true,
        Sparse:true
    }
);
```

flavors = array with embedded attributes id, name.

```
"flavors":[
    {
       "id":"123",
       "name":"name123"
    }
]
```

status = String
createdDate = ISO Date

Attributes status and createdDate are already existing fields present in each of the document as mandatory values.

So when the above index was created, the size of index was in GBs where as the expected size was in KBs as the preceding index attribute is fairly a new one and not present in any of the documents.

Despite providing sparse as "true", still the index size was more. Please share some thoughts on the way the index got built.

Comment: Since the other fields exist and are mandatory, [the index won't be as sparse](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-compound-indexes) as you are implying. Perhaps you want a [partial index instead](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/index-partial/)?

Comment: @user20042973 - yes, I then tried with the partial filter index with the filter query as "flavors.id":$exists true and then the index size was as expected to be in KBs. My understanding about the index build is, preceding column is the determining value to build index and sparse will make the whole composite key as unique condition. Are these not the expected behaviour?

Comment: That's not the behavior. From the docs I linked, emphasis added: "_Only indexes documents that contain a value for **at least one of the keys**._" It says nothing about the placement (eg preceding or otherwise) of those fields in the index definition

Comment: @user20042973 -  yeah I saw that link too, but somehow I was caught with the statement **"Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field"** as unique combination. It seems like for a composite key, all the keys in the index have to be sparse only then its a true sparse.